# Python edit csv File

Tags: python, csv

I want to edit a csv file. A value should be exchanged if another value is smaller than a previously determined value by me.
I have different values in the csv File.
The Header look like this:
SAP-Nu;Name;Version;Typ;Aktiv;IP;Srv;LastChan

"LastChan" is written in DD.MM.YY
"Akitv" is ture or false

Now I want change the part "Aktiv" from true to false if the value from "LastChan" is older then 30 Days.

In the csv File are just around 2500 - 4000 Lines. I dont want check them by myself ;-)

The csv File will be used to genareate a SQLite Database.
I try to change the value from "Aktiv" with a SQL Query.
But the Problem is the Date Format from the File.
Normaly it should be YYYY-MM-DD or somethin like this, but i have DD.MM.YY

The csv File is an Export from another System, i cannot change the way or customize the external system that the csv File will be written correctly from the Date-Format.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def CheckDate(lastchan: str, limit: int = 30)->bool:
    day, month, year = lastchan.split(".")
    formal_date = datetime.date(int("20"+year), int(month), int(day))
    return abs((datetime.date.today() - formal_date).days) <= limit
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. This Code should i combinate with csv reader to modify the csv file ? In the end i have a correct Timestamp in the csv File and with this i could use the sql query, right ?

Comment: Yes, you need read the csv file, for each line in the content you read, you can split them by ";" and use this function `CheckDate`. This function will receive the value in `LastChan` filed and return true if  `LastChan`  is not older than 30 Days, otherwise, it will return false.

Comment: Sorry i'm not able to use your solution. I don't have enought Python Skills for this.
If i open the csv file and call CheckDate("30.11.22") and print(row) i get all Information from the csv File.